# 6GHz GMSL2 signal over UTP, calculating insertion loss over cables

Tags: communication, digital-communications, protocol, attenuation, insertion

I'm doing some research into having CSI cameras at a distance of around 3m from a computer and am thinking of using a CSI to GMSL2 serializer deserializer pair, in particular, the MAX96724 and MAX96717. Analog Devices suggests using STP or Coax, but I want to explore the possibility of using UTP due to budgeting reasons. This is all new to me, so I apologise if it's this is a dumb question, but how would I go about calculating the insertion loss over a UTP cable? The GMSL2 System Channel specifications state that the maximum channel insertion loss is -21dB.
Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE.  Can you say what kind of UTP? CAT5, CAT6, etc?

Comment: @colintd I'm open to options. I'd need would be rated for 6GHz, however, and I'm struggling to find anything that would meet that spec.

Answer (score 0):

Check the cable's datasheet for its insertion loss per unit length (e.g. dB/100m) at different frequencies. You should also look for UTP cables with low signal attenuation at your desired frequency range, such as CAT6.

Comment: I've had a look at a few spec sheets and they don't seem to go up to the frequencies I'm after (6GHz), I guess because the cable isn't specked for this high frequency. Any suggestions?